# Bootstrap 3 .text-info and .bg-danger classes will not be applied

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code:

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center text-info bg-danger">
       RGBA Colors

       </div>
```

My problem is that text-info and bg-danger classes will not be applied.
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `.jumbotron` overrides values:

[image]

Just add the styling to your custom css (that follows the bootstrap one). These are only 4 selectors:

```
.bg-danger {
    background-color: #f2dede;
}
a.bg-danger:hover {
    background-color: #e4b9b9;
}

.text-info {
    color: #31708f;
}

a.text-info:hover {
    color: #245269;
}
```

You don't even need the aforementioned bootstrap classes to get the desired effect. You may create your own custom ones.

Answer (score 2):

The class `.jumbotron` also has a `color` and `background-color` defined. As it occurs later in Bootstrap's css it overrules those properties in `.text-info` and `.bg-danger`.

To get the `color` you want add it to a child `<div>`. One solution for the `background-color` is defining it in a custom stylesheet for the combination of both `.jumbotron` and `.bg-danger`. As this has higher specificity than `.jumbotron` only it will overrule the grey background color. But also rethink why you want a `.jumbotron` in the first place, do you really need it?

```css
@import url('//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.jumbotron.bg-danger {
  background-color: #f2dede;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron text-center bg-danger">
  <div class="text-info">RGBA Colors</div>
</div>
```